Simplification of matrix multiplication
Let $B$ be an $n\times n$ invertible matrix with $B=B^T$ and $v,w$ a $n$ dimensional vector.
Can we simplify
$$\sum_{a=1}^{n}\sum_{b=1}^n\sum_{c=1}^n\sum_{d=1}^nB^{-1}_{a,b} v_b B_{b,c} w_c B^{-1}_{c,d}?$$
Having tried some examples I think it could be $$\sum_{a=1}^n\sum_{b=1}^nv_aB^{-1}_{a,b}w_b.$$
I tried to prove this relation using the transposedness condition and the definition of matrix multiplication.

Move the factors $B^{-1}{a,b}$ and $B^{-1}{c,d}$ to be next to the $B_{b,c}$ in the middle and then contract adjacent pairs of indices.
